# Compare two arrays by hash code

Tags: java, arrays, reflection

I have two instances of the same class:

```
Object instance1;
Object instance2;
```

I know that the class in question has an array field. I need to compare the identityHashCode of the  array field, and in some cases I expect it to be the same.

The thing is that they are always different. I am guessing that is to be expected since they are in effect two different instances.

Is there a way to compare two arrays disregarding what elements they hold?

I am using Java reflection to get the value of the arrays.

Comment: What? How would you ever compare two arrays *disregarding* what elements they hold? The only useful information then could be "are they the same object", in which case `==` gives you all that you need.

Comment: Have you tried using `Arrays.hashCode()` or `Arrays.deepHashCode()` ?

Comment: What does it mean to compare two arrays but disregard the elements in them?

Comment: I know it's awkward, but I kinda have to compare their memory position. And System.identityHashCode() did that, but I can't use that.

Comment: @Tiago if you can't use identityHashCode() then I'm afraid it's not possible.

Comment: Well I could, but then it would always return differently since they are different instances.

Comment: @Tiago Have you tried `toString()`?  Since array is derived from `Object`, and `Object.toString()` is based on the memory address that might be of some help.  I assume you haven't overridden the `Array.toString()` method.  If you have then `super.toString()` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to compare two arrays disregarding what elements they
>   hold?

Sure, you could compare the component type and the size:

```
/**
 * Returns true iff two arrays of the same component type and
 * length are passed in.
 */
public static boolean pseudoArrayEquals(Object a, Object b){
    if(a==null||b==null||!a.getClass().isArray()||!b.getClass().isArray())
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expected two arrays");
    return a.getClass() == b.getClass()
           && Array.getLength(a) == Array.getLength(b);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could iterate over the arrays and call the `hashCode()` method on the objects. Note, however, that the base implementation (that in `Object`) returns a different hash code per instance.

If you want to check whether both arrays contain the same elements but possibly in different order, you should create two (hash)sets (i.e. `Set<Object>`) and call `containsAll(...)` on the sets (possibly mutually, since set 1 could be a superset of set 2). Assuming that the implicit contract of `equals()` and `hashCode()` is fulfilled (`"If two objects are equal according to the equals(Object) method, then calling the hashCode method on each of the two objects must produce the same integer result."`) , that would tell you whether both arrays contain the same elements.